# How do I create a custom javascript variable that selects part of an already existing javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to create a custom javascript variable in GTM that returns part of a javascript variable that already exists.

Variable that already exists: `window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta.product.variants.0.name`

returns this: `"Bamboo Basic String - Schwarz - S"`

However I want to code a custom javascript variable to just return the `Schwarz` part, is this possible? If so what is the code that I would need?

Please can someone let me know what code to put into GTM to create this variable?

TIA

Comment: Is the value always in this format `"word1 word2 word3 - word4 - word5"`?

Comment: Yes, it's always "product name - product colour - product size", and I am wanting to create a variable that gives me product colour only

Answer (score 0):

If all names are pretty much the same you could use split to get that part of string and then remove whitespaces. It would look like this:

> window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta.product.variants.0.name.split('-')[1].replace(/
> /g,'');

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am getting an error when I put this into GTM, I am using a custom javascript variable type and have inputted the following: 

' function ()
{
  return window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta.product.variants.0.name.split('-')[1].replace(/ /g,'');
}'

but the error I get says "Error at line 3, character 55: Parse error. Semi-colon expected"

Answer (score 0):

If the already existing variable is always structured the same way you could do something like this:

```js
let variable = window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta.product.variants.0.name.split('-')
```

Then by calling varaible[1] you get the 'Schwartz' part of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string on the hypens (`-`) like this:

```
const productName = window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta.product.variants.0.name;

const part = productName.split(' - ')[1];
```

Assuming you have a consistent format, and you always want the second part after that hyphen.

`split` will separate parts of a string into an array where it finds a match for the argument. The first index `[0]` will be the product name, the second `[1]` will be the part you're looking for.

This could cause issues if you have a product name with a `-` in it too though so use with care!

If it needs to be an anonymous function for GTM, you could try the following (though I'm not a GTM expert):

```
function () {
    const productName = window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta.product.variants.0.name;
    return productName.split(' - ')[1] || 'Unknown';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this is really useful. When I put this into GTM, it says "The javaScript must define a function with a return value.", do I need to add a 'return' command somewhere?

Comment: I've added an update which might work in GTM!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a return value you can use a function like the following and call it wherever you want.

Simply make sure to pass the correct argument `content`

```js
// Declaring a function getColor that returns the second element in the list, 
// trimmed (without spaces before and after)
const getColor = (content) => {
  return content.split('-')[1].trim();
}

const test = "Bamboo Basic String - Schwarz - S";
console.log(getColor(test));

//console.log(getColor(window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta.product.variants.0.name));
```